# PHPのMemcache Extensionを入れても、「PHP Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found」になる

Tags: php, wordpress, memcached

WordPressでMemcacheを使ったオブジェクトキャッシュをしようと、[Memcached Object Cacheプラグイン](https://wordpress.org/plugins/memcached/)の`object-cache.php`を`/wp-content/`以下に設置しました。

すると、`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcache' not found`のエラーが出たので、指示通りに`sudo yum -y install php-pecl-memcache`を実行してMemcache Extensionを入れて、`service httpd restart`でApache再起動しても同じ状況のままでした。
`Memcached`の方もインストールしてみても結果は同じでした。

`/etc/php.d/memcache.ini`のファイルのは存在し、その中で`extension=memcache.so`で読み込んでいるのも確認しました。

この状況の解決方法をご存知の方いれば教えていただきたいです。お願いします。